# Searching For Text Objects By Their Content

Tags: text-object

Are there any way (maybe using an add-on) to find and select the "text object" in Blender using the text it is containing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple script**

[image]

Here is a simple little bare bones script to select only text objects, and only text objects that contain the string as defined by

```
string = "Find this in text bodies"
```

Copy and paste this in text editor, edit string and hit run script.

```
import bpy

string = "Text"

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

def text_in_body(o, s):
    if o.type != 'FONT':
        return False
    return s in o.data.body

for o in scene.objects:
    o.select_set(text_in_body(o, string))
```

If using 2.7x or before change last line to

```
    o.select = text_in_body(o, string)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.

Comment: And how would this script looked if I needed to find not exact phrase but a part of the word (not case sensitive)?

Comment: Case insensitive `return string.lower() in o.data.body.lower()`  ... case insensitive starting with `return o.data.body.lower().startswith(string.lower())`

Comment: Perfect! (As far as I understood I can type "s.lower()" in stead of "string.lower()" )